# Elastic Search node not forming cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to setup a ES cluster over windows machine using uni cast. I think I have made all required configuration changes, but still my ES nodes do not form cluster.Could someone please let me know what I am missing. Please find below  my elasticseach.yml configurations

```
   =======Noed 8=======
    cluster.name: elasticsearch
    node.name: NODE8
    node.data: true
    network.host: "10.249.167.8"
    network.publish_host: "10.249.167.8"
    network.bind: "10.249.167.8"
    discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
    discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["10.249.167.9", "10.249.167.10", "10.249.167.8"]

    transport.tcp.port: 9300

=======Node9 Config========
cluster.name: elasticsearch
node.name: NODE9
node.data: true
network.host: "10.249.167.9"
network.publish_host: "10.249.167.9"
network.bind: "10.249.167.9"
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false

discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["10.249.167.9", "10.249.167.10", "10.249.167.8"]

transport.tcp.port: 9300

I can query both ES node individually, but they dont form cluster

Node 8 Get : http://10.249.167.8:9200/_cat/nodes?h=ip,port,heapPercent,name
10.249.167.8 9300 2 Cecilia Reyes

Node 9 Get : http://10.249.167.9:9200/_cat/nodes?h=ip,port,heapPercent,name
10.249.167.9 9300 9 Victorius

Following are the startup logs, any help would be appreciated a ton, I am stuck on this for a while now:(
[2016-02-13 01:08:06,395][WARN ][bootstrap ] unable to install syscall filter: syscall filtering not supported for OS: 'Windows Server 2012 R2'
[2016-02-13 01:08:06,645][INFO ][node ] [NODE8] version[2.1.1], pid[7628], build[40e2c53/2015-12-15T13:05:55Z]
[2016-02-13 01:08:06,645][INFO ][node ] [NODE8] initializing ...
[2016-02-13 01:08:07,020][INFO ][plugins ] [NODE8] loaded [cloud-azure], sites []
[2016-02-13 01:08:07,051][INFO ][env ] [NODE8] using [1] data paths, mounts [[(C:)]], net usable_space [94.6gb], net total_space [126.6gb], spins? [unknown], types [NTFS]
[2016-02-13 01:08:09,170][INFO ][node ] [NODE8] initialized
[2016-02-13 01:08:09,170][INFO ][node ] [NODE8] starting ...
[2016-02-13 01:08:09,357][INFO ][transport ] [NODE8] publish_address {10.249.167.8:9300}, bound_addresses {10.249.167.8:9300}
[2016-02-13 01:08:09,373][INFO ][discovery ] [NODE8] elasticsearch/i42Qv-qNSJaSoLRCt2e5tg
[2016-02-13 01:08:13,936][INFO ][cluster.service ] [NODE8] new_master {NODE8}{i42Qv-qNSJaSoLRCt2e5tg}{10.249.167.8}{10.249.167.8:9300}, reason: zen-disco-join(elected_as_master, [0] joins received)
[2016-02-13 01:08:13,983][INFO ][http ] [NODE8] publish_address {10.249.167.8:9200}, bound_addresses {10.249.167.8:9200}
[2016-02-13 01:08:13,983][INFO ][node ] [NODE8] started
[2016-02-13 01:08:16,715][INFO ][gateway ] [NODE8] recovered [1] indices into cluster_state

Node 9 Log========================================================================

[2016-02-13 01:08:44,988][WARN ][bootstrap ] unable to install syscall filter: syscall filtering not supported for OS: 'Windows Server 2012 R2'
[2016-02-13 01:08:45,237][INFO ][node ] [NODE9] version[2.1.1], pid[6468], build[40e2c53/2015-12-15T13:05:55Z]
[2016-02-13 01:08:45,237][INFO ][node ] [NODE9] initializing ...
[2016-02-13 01:08:45,601][INFO ][plugins ] [NODE9] loaded [cloud-azure], sites []
[2016-02-13 01:08:45,625][INFO ][env ] [NODE9] using [1] data paths, mounts [[(C:)]], net usable_space [113.6gb], net total_space [126.6gb], spins? [unknown], types [NTFS]
[2016-02-13 01:08:47,554][INFO ][node ] [NODE9] initialized
[2016-02-13 01:08:47,554][INFO ][node ] [NODE9] starting ...
[2016-02-13 01:08:47,753][INFO ][transport ] [NODE9] publish_address {10.249.167.9:9300}, bound_addresses {10.249.167.9:9300}
[2016-02-13 01:08:47,763][INFO ][discovery ] [NODE9] elasticsearch/ys7WjfT3QR2DqwLFr-m6Ew
[2016-02-13 01:08:52,292][INFO ][cluster.service ] [NODE9] new_master {NODE9}{ys7WjfT3QR2DqwLFr-m6Ew}{10.249.167.9}{10.249.167.9:9300}, reason: zen-disco-join(elected_as_master, [0] joins received)
[2016-02-13 01:08:52,342][INFO ][http ] [NODE9] publish_address {10.249.167.9:9200}, bound_addresses {10.249.167.9:9200}
[2016-02-13 01:08:52,342][INFO ][node ] [NODE9] started
[2016-02-13 01:08:53,649][INFO ][gateway ] [NODE9] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is looks like split brain problem.

It means the node gets separated and act as master on their own.

From your logs, its clearly visible that your nodes had created two different clusters literally.

to avoid the split brain, the possible way is 
**mentioning the minimum master nodes**

```
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes
```

can be calculated by using following calculation

```
minimum master node = (N/2)+1
```

where N is number of nodes

for example, if you are having 3 nodes in your cluster, you can set as

```
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2
```